# Access SQL: Format a calculation as a percentage (Numeric, not string)

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm working in Access 2010's SQL editor and I'm performing a calculation that results in a ratio.

I would like to display this ratio as a percentage using the SQL syntax editor, but as a number, not a string. I'd like to be able to paste out/export to Excel and not have to convert text to numbers.

Let's say this is my calculation:

```
OriginCount/DestinationCount AS MatchRate
```

I used the `FORMAT` function to make it appear as a percentage, but the result appears as a string. (Which I think is how the `FORMAT` function is designed to work)

```
FORMAT(OriginCount/DestinationCount,'Percent') AS MatchRate
```

Question 1: Is this possible using the SQL syntax editor?
Question 2: How do I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add a comment for suggested improvement if you're going to down vote.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How will you be using this data? It is standard to leave it as a double, EG: `0.02354`, and then simply change the format of any control displaying that field.

Users should not being seeing tables or queries without them being the recordsource of a form, so this shouldn't be a problem.

That way, when exporting to Excel/Wherever else, it will properly display as a decimal number, and when viewing in Access, it will display as a Percentage `2.35%`

Comment: Thanks for the reply JCro, I don't understand what you mean by changing the format of a control.  Can you expand on that?

Comment: For example, place a TextBox control on a form with a number table column recordsource. In design view on that form, you should be able to select the TextBox, go to the properties pane (Right hand side) and the third property from the top is "Format". You can type a custom format there, or select a preset. In this case you would select the preset "Percent". This will take the table value (let's say `0.02354`) and display it like this `2.35%`. That means the value stays a true decimal number, but the display is a formatted string.

Answer (score 0):

The result of the `FORMAT` function in access is always in string format, so that would be expected behavior.

Did you try the `CONVERT` function instead?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply bLunt, but it appears that the link applies to MS SQL Server